# MultyThreading debug (java or VS)

Tags: c#, java, multithreading, debugging, synchronization

I have an app that works perfectly)) I have wrote it in two variants - using parallel approach and simple step-by-step and even got the same results... But! In VERY rare case my parallel code produce duplicate data. There is a VERY little piece of them - for 400-500 Mb of valid data I get only 7 to 20 bytes of trash and even not with each program run.. But I don't like it! I have used synchronized data storage but it is third party code*. So I suppose that problem is there. But how could I debug this exotic situation?

*I have the code of this third party storage

Comment: Do you know if it is C# or Java, or is it both?

Comment: Never mind really) I could port a code of my core to c# and use it with VS debug tools or left it in java IDE(that sadly has more poor debug tools as for my view)

Comment: Debuggers are not really suitable for detecting race conditions between threads.  Nothing compares to keeping the code simple and understanding exactly what your code is doing.

Comment: You are very right =) I am trying to be self-critical and keep in mind that simplicity is a keY)) In fact I could port only my core(. 3rd party storage code I have only for java version( and only dll for win((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that there is some kind of race condition you are not taking into account. Debugging race conditions can be tricky since you'll end up changing the timing by adding any code. The best thing to do is go back and really think through it where the data is being corrupted.

I will add one thing though that caught me up with synchronization. I don't know about your third-party stuff, but I was using objects for synchronization (an android thing?). I made the mistake of using a Boolean object which only ever points to one of two objects (True or False). So while my objects were named different things, I was really synchronizing on the same objects that they pointed to!

Not sure if this helps at all, but good luck! Multi-Threading can be tricky! We'd likely need the major code parts to really look into the issue.